# How to write bin file (512 bytes) to first sector (sector 0) of floppy *.img file?

Tags: linux, bin, floppy

I knew use `dd if=a.bin of=a.img bs=512 count=1` commond can write a bin file to *.img file in ubuntu 15.10 ,
i got a file size equals the bin file , it's to small , i can't copy any other files to this img file

how do i write bin file to a exist img file

thanks a lot

Comment: Make some C program (or script in Python, Ocaml, ...) to build the entire `.img` file from different constituents. Or consider some `ld` script

Comment: thank a lot.  I made a c program to deal with it,than it works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write a bin file (512 bytes) to the first sector (sector 0) of a floppy disk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893607/how-do-i-write-a-bin-file-512-bytes-to-the-first-sector-sector-0-of-a-floppy)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in two pass:

```
dd if=a.bin of=a_m.img bs=512 count=1
dd if=a.img of=a_m.img conv=notrunc oflag=append bs=512 skip=1
```