# Enable the boot loader to load the second sector of a USB

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, osdev, bochs

I am learning the assembly language. I wrote a simple bootloader. After testing it out, it didn't work. Here is my code:

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]

jmp start

data:
wolf_wel_msg db 'Welcome to Bootloader!!!',0x0D,0x0A,0
wolf_kernel_load db 'Loading kernel....',0x0D,0x0A,0
wolf_error_msg db 'Kernel.bin not found!',0x0D,0x0A,0
wolf_error_msg1 db 'Press any key to restart..',0

start:
        mov si, wolf_wel_msg
    call wolf_print

    mov si, wolf_kernel_load
    call wolf_print

    pushf
    stc

    mov ah,00
    mov dl,00
    int 13h

    read_sector:
            mov ax, 0x0
        mov es, ax
        xor bx, bx
            mov ah, 02
        mov al, 01
        mov ch, 01
        mov cl, 02
        mov dh, 00
        mov dl, 00
        int 13h

    jc wolf_error
    popf
    jmp 0x0:0x1000
    cli
    hlt

    wolf_error:
            mov si, wolf_error_msg
        call wolf_print
        mov si, wolf_error_msg1
        call wolf_print
            mov ah,00
        int 16h
        xor ax,ax
        int 19h

    wolf_print:
            lodsb 
        or al,al
        jz exit
        mov ah,0x0e
        int 10h
        jmp wolf_print
        exit:
            ret

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

This code is placed in the first sector of the USB using this command:

```
dd if=f:\boot.bin of=\\.\d: bs=512 count=1
```

A simple program is loaded in the second sector of the USB using this command:

```
dd if=f:\hello.bin of=\\.\d: bs=512 seek=1 count=1
```

This is the code for the program loaded into the second sector:

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x1000]

jmp start
data:
   msg db 'Hello',0
start:
   mov si, msg
   jmp print

   cli
   hlt
   print:
      lodsb
      or al, al
      jz exit
      mov ah,0x0e
      int 10h
      jmp print
  exit:
      ret
```

Why is my boot loader not working? Have I done something wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried already? What exactly "doesn't work"? Do you get any output at all?

Comment: No I get output saying "kernel.bin not found". It means carry is set(Unsuccessful).

Comment: "hello.bin" not loaded from second sector.

Comment: Have you tried running it in an emulator such as QEMU to make debugging easier?

Comment: I tried it in Bochs emulator and also booted my system. Is my code correct?

Comment: I did all what you said but still not working

Comment: My code has mov ax,0 mov es, ax xor bx,bx Is that correct? Thanks for your valuable answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code assumes that *DS* is set to 0. You can't assume that. First part of your code should explicitly set *DS* to 0 if you are using `org 0x7c00`.

You should seriously considering defining your stack by setting *SS:SP*. You don't know where the existing one is or whether it is large enough to handle what you intend to do.

Just prior to your bootloader being called, the BIOS will set the *DL* register with the boot device number. You should not be setting *DL* to 0 in your code when making drive requests from the boot drive. You should be using the value that existed in *DL* when your bootloader was called.

You should use the *CLD* instruction to clear the direction flag since you are using the *LODSB* instruction expecting to be moving forward in memory. There isn't a guarantee the direction flag will be properly set so you should explicitly set it to the direction you need with *CLD*(forward) or *STD*(backward).

I have more information on the issues above in my StackOverflow answer with [General Bootloader Tips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076/3857942).

Since you are not using a [BPB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_parameter_block) then I highly recommend removing the `jmp start` as the first instruction of your bootloader. Instead move the data after the code but before the boot sector signature (`0xAA55`). The reason for that is some BIOSes will attempt to find a *BPB* based on a *JMP* instruction appearing as the first instruction of the bootloader, and if found overwrites parts of your bootloader in memory causing potentially undefined behavior.

Your bootloader uses this instruction to start your second stage loaded from the second sector:

```
jmp 0x0:0x1000
```

The problem is that when you read the sector setting up *ES:BX* this way:

```
read_sector:
    mov ax, 0x0
    mov es, ax
    xor bx, bx
```

This sets *ES:BX* to 0x0000:0x0000 which is clearly not where your *JMP* expects the code to be. You need to set *ES:BX* to the memory location you want [INT 13/AH=02h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0607.htm) to read the disk sector(s) into.

*INT 13h/AH=02h* requires Cylinder/Head/Sector number to be set properly. Sectors start numbering at 1, but Cylinders and Heads are zero based. The second sector of the disk is at Cylinder 0, Head 0, Sector 2. Your code sets Cylinder to 1 instead of 0. This code is wrong since you really should be setting it to 0:

```
mov ch, 01
```

In your second stage you created `print` as a function since it ends with a `RET` instruction.  `jmp print` should be changed to `call print`.

With all the changes recommended above, including ones from my general bootloader tips your code could be modified to be:

**boot.asm**

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]

                   ; Use the boot drive number passed to us by BIOS in register DL
start:
    xor ax,ax      ; We want a segment of 0 for DS for this question
    mov ds,ax      ;     Set AX to appropriate segment value for your situation
    mov es,ax      ; In this case we'll default to ES=DS
    mov bx,0x8000  ; Stack segment can be any usable memory

    mov ss,bx      ; This places it with the top of the stack @ 0x80000.
    mov sp,ax      ; Set SP=0 so the bottom of stack will be @ 0x8FFFF

    cld            ; Set the direction flag to be positive direction

    mov si, wolf_wel_msg
    call wolf_print

    mov si, wolf_kernel_load
    call wolf_print

    pushf
    stc

    mov ah,00
    int 13h

    read_sector:
        mov ax, 0x0
        mov es, ax      ; ES = 0
        mov bx, 0x1000  ; BX = 0x1000. ES:BX=0x0:0x1000 
                        ; ES:BX = starting address to read sector(s) into
        mov ah, 02      ; Int 13h/AH=2 = Read Sectors From Drive
        mov al, 01      ; Sectors to read = 1
        mov ch, 00      ; CH=Cylinder. Second sector of disk
                        ; is at Cylinder 0 not 1
        mov cl, 02      ; Sector to read = 2
        mov dh, 00      ; Head to read = 0
                        ; DL hasn't been destroyed by our bootloader code and still
                        ;     contains boot drive # passed to our bootloader by the BIOS
        int 13h

    jc wolf_error
    popf
    jmp 0x0:0x1000
    cli
    hlt

    wolf_error:
        mov si, wolf_error_msg
        call wolf_print
        mov si, wolf_error_msg1
        call wolf_print
        mov ah,00
        int 16h
        xor ax,ax
        int 19h

    wolf_print:
        lodsb
        or al,al
        jz exit
        mov ah,0x0e
        int 10h
        jmp wolf_print
        exit:
        ret

; Moved the data before the boot signature but after the code
wolf_wel_msg db 'Welcome to Bootloader!!!',0x0D,0x0A,0
wolf_kernel_load db 'Loading kernel....',0x0D,0x0A,0
wolf_error_msg db 'Kernel.bin not found!',0x0D,0x0A,0
wolf_error_msg1 db 'Press any key to restart..',0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

**hello.asm**

```
[org 0x1000]

jmp start
data:
   msg db 'Hello',0
start:
   mov si, msg
   call print      ; print is a function, use CALL instead of JMP

   cli
   hlt
   print:
      lodsb
      or al, al
      jz exit
      mov ah,0x0e
      int 10h
      jmp print
  exit:
      ret
```

---

Since it appears you are using Windows based upon the information given in your *DD* command, you may be running into another problem. I don't know which *DD* you are using but `of=\\.\d:` doesn't write to the beginning of the disk (USB drive), it will write to the partition that D: resides in, not the beginning of the disk itself.

I recommend you use the latest *DD* from [Chrysocome](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd). As of today the latest is [0.6beta3](http://www.chrysocome.net/downloads/dd-0.6beta3.zip). I recommend this version because it allows you to properly access the disk(or USB stick) relative to the beginning of the drive, not relative to the beginning of a particular partition. This could cause serious problems trying to store the 1st and 2nd sector properly. With the latest version I'd use these commands with **Administrator Privileges** to write to the USB drive:

```
dd if=f:\boot.bin od=d: bs=512 count=1
dd if=f:\hello.bin od=d: bs=512 seek=1 count=1
```

This assumes your *USB* drive is on Drive D: as is suggested in your question. **WARNING: Failure to use the correct drive may result in data loss and corruption on another device!!**

If these commands work properly the output should look something like:

> ```
> dd if=boot.bin od=d: bs=512 count=1
> rawwrite dd for windows version 0.6beta3.
> Written by John Newbigin <jn@it.swin.edu.au>
> This program is covered by terms of the GPL Version 2.
>
> Device d: is a link to \\?\Device\HarddiskVolume5 \\?\Device\HarddiskVolume5 is a partition on \Device\Harddisk1
> 512 100%
> 1+0 records in
> 1+0 records out
>
> dd if=hello.bin od=d: bs=512 seek=1 count=1
> rawwrite dd for windows version 0.6beta3.
> Written by John Newbigin <jn@it.swin.edu.au>
> This program is covered by terms of the GPL Version 2.
>
> Device d: is a link to \\?\Device\HarddiskVolume5 \\?\Device\HarddiskVolume5 is a partition on \Device\Harddisk1
> 28 5%
> 0+1 records in
> 0+1 records out
> ```

Once you have issued these commands, Windows may automatically detect that the drive is no longer properly formatted. Do not allow Windows to format the drive. If you do allow it to format the drive, it will re-partition it, and format it. In doing so it will destroy the boot sector you wrote. When prompted, just cancel the *format* dialog box that may appear.

Remember to properly dismount/eject your USB drive before removing it from your system. Failure to properly unmount will likely cause the data to not be properly/completely written to the drive.

If you wish create a disk image for Bochs, QEMU, DOSbox etc you could create a 720k floppy with these commands at a Command Prompt:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=1024 count=720    
dd if=f:\boot.bin of=disk.img bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc
dd if=f:\hello.bin of=disk.img bs=512 seek=1 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

The image file `disk.img` should be usable by Bochs, QEMU, DOSbox, etc. or written to a 720k diskette for use on a real computer.

`/dev/zero` looks like a typical Unix/Linux device. The *DD* command for Windows I suggested you use understands `/dev/zero` as a special input device that just generates zeros. Windows doesn't have `/dev/zero` device, but *DD* sees it as a special internal device and simulates it.

---

When run with Bochs 2.6.8 on MS Windows this is what I saw:

[image]

On my Lenovo L520 Laptop (non-EFI BIOS) with a 16GB USB Stick this is what I saw:

[image]