# How Do I Put My Bootloader And Kernel On A USB

Tags: x86, usb, nasm, bootloader, osdev

I've written a bootloader and Basic kernel as a fun side project while i'm learning 2 stage bootloaders, I want to load my bootloader at sector 1 (or the MBR) of the USB and the Kernel at sector 2. I've compiled both into Bootloader.bin & Kernel.bin using NASM. I just need a little help on actually writing them onto the USB. I have access to both Windows and Linux so any answers a appreciated.

Bootloader.asm

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]

ResetDisk:
XOR AH, AH
INT 0x13
JC ResetDisk

ReadDisk:
MOV BX, 0x8000
MOV ES, BX
MOV BX, 0x0000

MOV AH, 0x02
MOV AL, 1
MOV CH, 0x00
MOV CL, 0x02
MOV DH, 0x00
INT 0x13
JC ResetDisk
JMP 0x8000:0x0000

TIMES 510-($-$$) DB 0
DW 0xAA55
```

Kernel.asm

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x8000]

MOV SI, HelloString
CALL PrintString
JMP $

PrintChar:
MOV AH, 0x0E
MOV BH, 0x00
MOV BL, 0x0F
RET

PrintString:
MOV AL, [SI]
INC SI
OR AL, AL
JZ Exit
CALL PrintChar
JMP PrintString
Exit:
RET

HelloString DB 'Hello World!',0

TIMES 512-($-$$) DB 0
```

Comment: Maybe this SO answer may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044706/enable-the-boot-loader-to-load-the-second-sector-of-a-usb/36052385#36052385

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure out which device represents the USB key in `/dev` (the key itself, NOT a partition on it), then you can simply use `dd` or a similar tool to copy your data.

Example, where `/dev/xxx` is your USB key:

```
cat Bootloader.bin Kernel.bin > image.bin
sudo dd if=image.bin of=/dev/xxx bs=4k
```

Note that you may have to `umount` any mounted partition that comes from the USB key first. Also note that, but this goes without saying, **make sure there is nothing important on the USB key first**.